# Is the divorce via SMS valid, if at the time of divorce the wife was having her menses and she only got one of the three divorce messages?

Tags: talaq, menses

I was given advice by my friend to divorce my wife and he was not clear to me or explained me the procedure and I was angry and in doubt about doing it but he and my brother pushed me. So I did and  he asked me to SMS my wife that I am giving you talaaq and she got the first message and didn't get the other two.

But my wife told me a day later that she was not clean, that she was having her menses and after a few days my friends told me that I am divorcd.

So I will like to know where does my marriage stand in this case because if she didn't get the message and secondly she was not clean at the time when she received the message?

Comment: Please note that marriage and talaq matters are very serious things http://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/13/10

Answer (score 4):

> I was given advice by my friend to divorce my wife and he was not
>   clear to me or explained me the procedure and I was angry and in doubt
>   about doing it but he and my brother pushed me.

First of all, you should never take such a major decision as divorce when angry. In Islam, divorce is highly discouraged, but the provision is there in order to maintain harmony and avoid any injustice.

Divorce should be handled thus:

1. Appoint an arbitrator from both parties [4:35](http://quran.com/4/35):

> And if you fear dissension between the two, send an arbitrator from
>   his people and an arbitrator from her people. If they both desire
>   reconciliation, Allah will cause it between them. Indeed, Allah is
>   ever Knowing and Acquainted [with all things].

2. Wait 4 months (cooling off period) [2:226](http://quran.com/2/226):

> For those who swear not to have sexual relations with their wives is a
>   waiting time of four months, but if they return [to normal relations]
>   - then indeed, Allah is Forgiving and Merciful.

3. You must have 2 witnesses [65:2](http://quran.com/65/2):

> And when they have [nearly] fulfilled their term, either retain them
>   according to acceptable terms or part with them according to
>   acceptable terms. And bring to witness two just men from among you and
>   establish the testimony for [the acceptance of] Allah . That is
>   instructed to whoever should believe in Allah and the Last day. And
>   whoever fears Allah - He will make for him a way out

As far as divorce during her menses in [65:1](http://quran.com/65/1):

> O Prophet, when you [Muslims] divorce women, divorce them for [the
>   commencement of] their waiting period and keep count of the waiting
>   period, and fear Allah , your Lord. Do not turn them out of their
>   [husbands'] houses, nor should they [themselves] leave [during that
>   period] unless they are committing a clear immorality. And those are
>   the limits [set by] Allah . And whoever transgresses the limits of
>   Allah has certainly wronged himself. You know not; perhaps Allah will
>   bring about after that a [different] matter.

In the above translation "their waiting period" is her menses. Some more discussion and references from http://islamqa.info/en/72417:

> Shaykh Ibn Baaz (may Allaah have mercy on him) said: Divorce of a
>   menstruating woman does not count as such according to the more sound
>   of the two scholarly opinions, which is contrary to the view of the
>   majority. The majority of scholars think that it does count as such,
>   but the correct scholarly view is that reflected in the fatwas of some
>   of the Taabi’een and in the fatwa of Ibn ‘Umar (may Allaah be pleased
>   with him). This is also the view favoured by Shaykh al-Islam Ibn
>   Taymiyah and his student Ibn al-Qayyim and a number of scholars who
>   said that this divorce does not count as such, because it is contrary
>   to the laws of Allah. Allah decreed that a woman should be divorced
>   when she is in a state of purity, free from nifaas (postpartum
>   bleeding) and menses, and during a time of purity when her husband has
>   not yet had intercourse with her. This is the divorce that is
>   prescribed according to sharee’ah. If he divorces her during her
>   menses or nifaas, or during a time of purity when he has had
>   intercourse with her, then his divorce is bid’ah (an innovation) and
>   does not count as such according to the more sound of the two
>   scholarly views

Please do not take divorce lightly and I am kind of surprised you thought sending 3 SMS with "I divorce you" would work.